# Retrieving the previous key-map value before it was overwritten in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created a `HashMap` as per my code...

```
HashMap map=new HashMap();//HashMap key random order.
map.put("Amit","Java");
map.put("Saral","J2EE");
map.put("Saral","Andriod");//same key but different value 
map.put("Nitin","PHP");
map.put("hj","Spring1");
System.out.println("There are "+map.size()+" elements in the map.");
System.out.println("Content of Map are...");
Set s=map.entrySet();

Iterator itr=s.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
    System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+m.getValue()+"\t"+ m.hashCode());
    }
```

When I execute this code, the value for `key=Saral` is `Android`. Is there any way that I can get the previous value for this key, which was `J2EE`?

Comment: If you use `HashMap` it would not store different values for the same key. It would override with the latest value. Try reading on open addressing and separate chaining.

Comment: I know the overriding principle but for research I was asking this in the thread, please advise..!!

Comment: If you like the answer @PéterTörök provided please click on the checkmark below the vote count.  It's a great answer, and had some nice updates as well.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't have that with a standard `HashMap`. The easiest solution would be to store a `List` as value in the map though, and then you can add multiple items to the list (Btw you should use generic collections too). To simplify, you could use a helper method like this:

```
void addToMap(Map<String, List<String>> map, String key, String value) {
  List<String> list = map.get(key);

  if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    map.put(key, list);
  }
  list.add(value);
}

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
addToMap(map, "Amit", "Java");
addToMap(map, "Saral", "J2EE");
addToMap(map, "Saral", "Andriod");//same key but different value 
addToMap(map, "Nitin", "PHP");
addToMap(map, "hj", "Spring1");
...
```

The helper method here is just an illustration - a full, robust implementation may need to include e.g. checks for duplicate values, depending on whether you allow them. If not, you may prefer using a `Set` instead of `List`.

#### Update

To print out the contents of this map, you need to use an embedded loop to iterate through the list of values for each map entry (btw you can use a foreach loop instead of an iterator):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> m : map.entrySet())
{
  for (String v : m.getValue())
  {
    System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+v+"\t"+ m.hashCode());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Petrer , thanks a lot can you please show the small program that will make understandings more clearer..!! thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Hi Peter, please show the small program that will make understandings more clearer..!!

Comment: Hi Peter, I have gone through your implementation , thanks a lot, request you if you could provide at least full implementation as I have provided in the above , that will be a great help, since few things are not clear..!1thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Peter, I have gone through your implementation , thanks a lot, request you if you could provide at least full implementation as I have provided in the above , that will be a great help, since few things are not clear..!1thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` can contain at most one entry per key, so when you call `map.put("Saral","Andriod")`, the old `"J2EE"` value is removed. To support multiple values per key, you would need to maintain a `Map<String, List<String>>` or else a multi-map implementation such as Guava's [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

As a side note I would recommend you start using generics, for example `Map<String, String>`, `Iterator<String>`, etc. for type safety at compile time.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks  a lot that what I was looking for, thanks a lot, could you please show how my above program can be converted to store multiple values for saral key that will be a great help..!!through Map<String, List<String>> this mechanism

Answer (score 0):

The old value is overwritten (replaced). There will be only one mapping (entry) for one unique key. There fore it does not exist anymore so you can not retrieve it.

Comment: Hi , is there any multimap functionality is also provided by java..!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with standard implementations of `Map` that Java provides.  However there are implementations of MultiMap (that's basically what you're after).

One example is this one from Google:
http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Note that you won't be able to just get this one interface, you'll need a few classes along with it.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, this won't work with a standard Map.  However, Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides a [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface, which you can use to store multiple values with a single key.

Example of use:

```
Multimap<String,String> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multiMap.put("color", "red");
multiMap.put("color", "blue");
System.out.println(multiMap.get("color")); //returns a ["red', "blue"] list
```

Comment: Hi Greg thanks a lot, so finally there is no way in java to store multiple values with a single key..!! :)

Comment: Correct, not using the standard Collections api, but there are otherlibraries that will allow you too, or roll your own, as @peter-torok did.